# How to list all network connections Centos 7 (Connection tracking)

Tags: networking, kernel, iptables, network-interface, netfilter

I have a box with **Centos 7** installed.

I am trying to configure some **iptables rules** and playing with **the mangle table** and **markings**

For example on my router I am able to see established network connections with the following command in memory mapped fs (proc).

```
cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

But in my current centos installation I don't have any of similar files mapped to the proc fs.

Here is the output of grepping kernel modules

```
[root@testenv crosp]# lsmod | grep nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_netlink    36864  0 
nf_conntrack          106496  1 nf_conntrack_netlink
nfnetlink              16384  4 nfnetlink_log,ip_set,nf_conntrack_netlink
```

I have found the **ss** utility, but didn't found any information how to see packets marks.

How can I get information about established connections and about marked packages ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Following are some ways to extract established connection information:

1. cat **/proc/net/ip_conntrack** -> using proc filesystem
2. **conntrack**  -L -> command line interface for netfilter connection tracking. You can yum install it.
3. Another way is to write an iptable rule to LOG messages (use -j LOG) after your marking rule. Since marking rule is non terminating LOG rule will hit and it can be seen using dmesg.

For options 1 & 2 refer [this link](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html) section "Chapter 3. Requirements" in order to get the conntrack-tools working if they doesn't work.